# Category page not showing

Tags: categories, design

I installed wordpress 4.7.3. 
After that I created one "Test" category. 
After that I created one post and assigned to that "Test" category. 
Then I go to front end, in the right menu and clicked on "Test" category.

Then it shows page with text "OOPS! THAT PAGE CAN’T BE FOUND."
"It looks like nothing was found at this location. Maybe try a search?"

Using default wordpress theme "Twenty Seventeen".

Please why it is not showing category page with post assigned to that category?

Comment: What are your permalinks set to?

Comment: @mayerdesing not changed by default it is showing "Day and name http://localhost/wordpress/2017/04/19/sample-post/"

Comment: Have you published that post or just saved as a draft?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just save your permalinks. And the problem should be resolved.

Go to : Settings > Permalinks > Click 'Save Changes'

Comment: Mark as accepted if it resolved your issue.

Comment: Will accept after 10 minutes.